# add subtree below more than one nodes in a graph

Tags: java, jung, subtree

I am using **Java JUNG 2.0.1** version. I understand basics of JUNG API.

I have a tree with root vertex as 1 [see Input graph]. 
Basically, I want to remove an edge (from:1 to:3) i.e. have sub-tree where root is vertex 3  and      add it below vertex 2 and vertex 5 **separately** [see Output graph].

I used getSubTree() and addSubTree() of TreeUtils.java.
But, it gives error  with stack trace :
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tree must not already contain child a.b.c
    at edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.DelegateTree.addChild(DelegateTree.java:182)
    at edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.DelegateTree.addEdge(DelegateTree.java:102)
    at edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.util.TreeUtils.addFromSubTree(TreeUtils.java:139)
    at edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.util.TreeUtils.addSubTree(TreeUtils.java:100)

```
Input graph :
```

[image: Input graph :]

```
Output graph :
```

[image: Output graph :]

Comment: Without having tested it (an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would be helpful here) : I'm pretty sure that you somehow have to *copy* the part of the graph that should appear *twice*. Otherwise, how should the graph remain in a "consistent" state? E.g. what should `g.getOutEdges(3)` return for the output graph? Depending on what your nodes are, you have to think about how you can make them "unique". That is, when your Nodes are simply `Integer` objects, then this will most likely not be possible at all, because you can't distinguish the both `3`-nodes that will exist in the output.

Comment: @Marco13 In real scenario , I have graph having vertex of custom class .E.g.    `Class X {String label; String property;}`     In my case, label and properties can be same for more than one vertex. So, I can think of making the object id of vertexes as uniqueness in graph. I shall than create 2 instances of sub-tree with vertex 3 with different object id. If I implement this way, my graph will be consistent too. How can I set uniqueness of vertexes as object Id in java JUNG?

Comment: Joshua gave you some pointer in the answer. One possible way is to use an internal ID that is unique for each node that is created. The important thing is to properly implement `hashCode` and `equals` for the objects that should be your nodes. It this is an issue, maybe you can extend your question accordingly (mand preferably add a MCVE)

Answer (score 0):

Marco13@ is correct.  Graph elements (nodes and edges) are required to be unique; think of them as elements of a set.

If you want two nodes to have the same label (or value, or some other associated data), there are several ways to go about doing this, as discussed here: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/jung/wiki/JUNGManual#UserData